# Mass email deletion outlook Office 365

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

We currently have a user who is having emails randomly deleted permanently in batches. We can confirmed they are being deleted via the O365 audit logs search.

We've checked that there are no rules or plugins that are effecting the account.

The user doesn't even receive the emails sometimes they are instantly deleted around 1839hrs.

We believe something is triggering the issue however we can't seem to find the source, this is happening occasionally with a few other users too.

Any help greatly appreciated.

- Office 365
- Outlook 2016
- Windows 10 Pro
- No one else has access to the mailbox
- Does have a linked phone, android (however no emails are ever deleted
  on phone just browsed out of hours)

Time and Date of issues from 1 user:

- Received - 25/05/17 Deleted - 01/06/17
- Received - 25&26/05/17 Deleted - 02/06/17

Another user:

- Received - 01/06/17 Deleted - 01/06/17
- But nothing happened on the 02/06/17

Key to point out though it's a large amount of emails (50-60) this is a small amount compared to those received.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60392/discussion-on-question-by-david-golding-mass-email-deletion-outlook-office-365).

Comment: @DavidGolding - There absolutely was need for that, the extended discussion was unnecessary noise, and the proper action was taken.  Your conversation still exists.

Comment: @Ramhound I disagree especially as after more than 4 comments, you have to choose to expand and see the rest. This is just admin for the sake of it, also in chat you cant see all the information I put in the question above.

Comment: @DavidGolding - There is a link to this question, in the chatroom, I don't understand the problem.  Your question should include the details from the comments, comments have never been something, that should exist forever.  If you want to blame somebody, for a moderator moving your comments into a chatroom, blame me.

Comment: The chatroom is the correct place for extended comments. It allows quicker communication that can be very helpful for an active issue, and it keeps this area focused on the question, which should be edited on an on-going basis to make sure it contains all relevant information.